# MPAndroidChart - Remove top border / axis since v2

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I upgraded MPAndroidChart from v1.7 to v2 and had to change a couple things.
One of the new things is that i now appear to have a top border for the maximum value.

[image: The top border is what i want to remove]

My code trying to hide all borders is like this:

```
    LineChart graph = (LineChart) connectionView.findViewById(R.id.graph);
    graph.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    graph.setDrawBorders(false);
    graph.setDescription("");

    YAxis yr = graph.getAxisRight();
    yr.setEnabled(false);
    yr.setDrawAxisLine(false);

    YAxis yl = graph.getAxisLeft();
    yl.setValueFormatter(formatierer);
    yl.setShowOnlyMinMax(true);
    yl.setDrawAxisLine(false);

    XAxis xl = graph.getXAxis();
    xl.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xl.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xl.setDrawAxisLine(false);

    yl.setAxisMaxValue((float) graphpoint_max);
```

Still - i have a line showing the maximum value. I want to have the values on the YAxis but have no horizontal axis lines / borders. I wasn't able to find any command to hide it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried calling `setDrawAxisLine(...)` or `setDrawGridLines(...)` on the `YAxis`?

Here is the [full axis documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-Axis).

And here is the [documentation for YAxis only](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/YAxis-%28YLabels%29).

Comment: Thanks for helping. Yes, i tried it, even though it's been unlikely to fix my problem as the issue is a horizontal axis, not a vertical one. I added my full code and a screenshot and would appreciate further ideas :)

Comment: try `yAxis.setDrawGridLines(...)`. It's all in the documentation.

Comment: I understand your point about the documentation. The point about me posting here is reading the documentation for two days straight and still neither finding what line this is part of (XAxis, YAxis, outer Border) nor how to hide it. `yl.setDrawGridLines(false)` worked, could you edit your primary answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 8):

remove whatever lines you want :)

```
...       
        //remove top border
        chart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(false);
        
        //remove left border
        chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawAxisLine(false);
        
        //remove right border
        chart.getAxisRight().setDrawAxisLine(false);
```

in case you want to remove all the grids, lines and labels

```
chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

chart.setHighlightFullBarEnabled(false);

chart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
chart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
chart.getAxisRight().setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(false);
chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawLabels(false);
chart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(false);
chart.getXAxis().setDrawLabels(false);
chart.getXAxis().setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(false);
chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The top line is drawn as part of the X axis. You need to call this to get rid of it: `chart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(false);`.