# How to hide x-axis values in Barchart of mpandroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using barchart from mpandroidchart library.

I want to hide the x-axis values, but I am not able to hide the values.
Please help me through it. I used the following code but it doesn't work.

```
barChart.getXAxis().removeAllLimitLines();
```

Answer (score 19):

You want to hide only the labels of the axis, call `xAxis.setDrawLabels(false)`

If you want to hide the whole axis, call `xAxis.setEnabled(false)`

It's all in the [**documentation**](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-Axis).

Comment: @Philipp Jahoda I am having y axis values in both side and x-axis values at top of the chart. How to remove the right side y-axis values and how to change the x axis values at bottom ? And also the x-Axis values(strings) has any character limits ?

Answer (score 3):

Workaround:

Define **transparent color**:

```
 <color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

And then, **set the axis line color**:

```
XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setAxisLineColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent))
```

Comment: Maybe this can be helpfull:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164862/mpandroidchart-remove-top-border-axis-since-v2

Comment: barChart.getAxisRight().setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));   this worked for me ,thanks

Comment: This is kind of a hack. See Phillipp's answer for a more technically correct solution.

Comment: This ans is not relevant to question but it definitely works  for hiding x-Axis (Line) instead of labels.